# From model vega matrix to market vega matrix

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility

I'm reading Antonie Savine's fascinating book Modern Computational Finance AAD and Parallel Simulations. However, I got a bit confused while reading and couldn't make sense of how it works in his work. To be more specific, in the following paragraphs:

> We developed, in the previous chapter, functionality to obtain the
> microbucket $\frac{\partial V_0}{\partial \sigma(S,t)}$ in constant
> time. We check-point this result into calibration to obtain
> $\frac{\partial V_0}{\partial \hat{\sigma}(K,t)}$ , what Dupire calls
> a superbucket.
>
> We are missing one piece of functionality: our IVS $\hat{\sigma(K,T)}$
> is defined in derived IVS classes, from a set of parameters, which
> nature depends on the concrete IVS. For instance, the Merton IVS is
> parameterized with a continuous volatility, jump intensity, and the
> mean and standard deviation of jumps. The desired derivatives are not
> to the parameters of the concrete IVS, but to a discrete set of
> implied Black and Scholes market-implied volatilities, irrespective of
> how these volatilities are produced or interpolated.
>
> To achieve this result, we are going to use a neat technique that
> professional financial system developers typically apply in this
> situation: we are going to define a risk surface: $$s(K,T)$$
>
> such that if we denote $\hat{\sigma}(K,T)$ the implied volatilities
> given by the concrete IVS, our calculations will not use these
> original implied volatilities, but implied volatilities shifted by the
> risk surface: $$\sum(K,T) = \hat{\sigma}(K,T) + s(K,T)$$
>
> Further, we interpolate the risk surface s(K,T) from a discrete set of
> knots: $$s_{ij} = s(K_i, T_j)$$
>
> that we call the risk view. All the knots are set to 0, so:
> $$\sum(K,T) = \hat{\sigma}(K,T)$$
>
> so the results of all calculations remain evidently unchanged by
> shifting implied volatilities by zero, but in terms of risk, we get:
> $$\frac{\partial}{\sigma(K,T)} = \frac{\partial }{\partial s(K,T)}$$
>
> The risk view does not affect the value, and its derivatives exactly
> correspond to derivatives to implied volatilities, irrespective of how
> these implied volatilities are computed.
>
> We compute sensitivities to implied volatilities as sensitivities to
> the risk view: $$\frac{\partial V_0}{\partial s_{ij}}$$ ...

In my understanding, the risk surface added to the implied volatlity should be zero, but I don't see how this translates from model risk to market risk by adding the risk surface, can anyone provide any intuition behind this process?

Comment: Usually market greeks are bump market (vol surface) and reprice (you can either recalibrate or not). Model greeks are bump model parameters (e.g. LV surface) and reprice. The rue surface is zero without a shock but not once you do shock it. Although I do not know the book, I think this is similar here.